# Como fazer um loop dentro de uma variavel em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, variáveis, loop

Tenho uma pagina `index.php`. Nela tem um `loop` que coleta linha por linha de uma tabela do banco de dados mySQL e insere nas variáveis que são enviadas para o arquivo `dashboard.js` onde tem o código abaixo.

```
var visitorsData = {
[CODE_PAIS]: TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS, //Brazil
};
```

O que eu quero é que a variável `visitorsData` do arquivo `dashboard.js` armazene a mesma quantidade de linha e informações que tem na minha tabela. 
OBS: A quantidade de linhas no banco de dados não é fixa.

Comment: Esse arquivo dashboard.js está sendo gerado pelo PHP, ou é um arquivo estático? Se estiver sendo gerada, como é o código que a gera?

Comment: Ele é estático! Pego apenas algumas variáveis do arquivo php.

Comment: Então eu não entendi. Você diz "O que eu quero é que a variável `visitorsData` do arquivo `dashboard.js` armazene **a mesma quantidade de linha e informações que tem na minha tabela**" e "A quantidade de linhas no banco de dados **não é fixa**", mas se ele é um arquivo estático, quando o banco de dados mudar e esse arquivo não mudar as quantidades ficarão diferentes, não?

Comment: Isso implica reescrever o conteúdo todo ?

Comment: É o seguinte. As únicas informações que o  arquivo  dashboard.js pega é os da variáveis globais CODE_PAIS e TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS que são geradas no arquivo index.php. Mas a cada loop que é feito no arquivo index.php as informações dessa variáveis mudam. Então eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de coletar todas as informações geradas no loop do index.php e não a ultima informação armazenada nessas variáveis.
O proposito é fazer a linha '[CODE_PAIS]: TOTAL_VISIT_PAIS, //Brazil' da variável visitorsData repetir a mesma quantidade de vezes e com as mesmas informações do loop do arquivo index.php

Comment: Então ele é dinâmico, e não estático! (se ele muda - nem que seja um pouquinho - ele não é estático) Eu tinha pedido pra você postar o código que gera essa variável, mas esquece, o que você está tentando fazer não me parece prático. PHP é (ou pelo menos deveria ser) *stateless*. Se você realmente precisa que dois arquivos diferentes (o que implica em duas requisições diferentes) se relacionem de alguma forma, o jeito é guardar alguns dados na sessão ao gerar o `index.php` e depois pegar esses mesmos dados ao gerar o `dashboard.js`. Pra garantir que não venha uma cópia antiga na cache, crie...

Comment: ...um elemento `<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard.js?dados=ID"></script>` no seu `index.php`, onde `ID` é a chave responsável por pegar os dados previamente armazenados na sessão (pode ter formas melhores, não tenho muita experiência com PHP então estou falando só sobre o que sei). Mas reiterando: se puder evitar fazer isso, evite! Você não poderia em vez disso colocar o JavaScript *inline* no próprio `index.php`, por exemplo?

Comment: Coloca o teu código... quanto mais mostrares mais te podemos ajudar. Assim estás a perder tempo e a criar perguntas e aceitar respostas que não resolvem o problema.